# Query on the performance standard deviation and relates to server performance

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, standard-deviation

I would like to know more about standard deviation and how it actually relates the performance of the server.

I ran a test where response time of the server is below - 280 ms(approx for all API)

Where i can see the std. dev as apprx 140 ms( all API falls into this)

from the above can u please help me to understand is the server perf is good ?
Also let we know if we can tell the server performance is consistant or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) wikipedia article:

> the standard deviation is a measure of the amount of variation or [dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion) of a set of values.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) A low standard deviation indicates that the values tend to be close to the mean (also called the expected value) of the set, while a high standard deviation indicates that the values are spread out over a wider range.

In ideal world you should have absolutely the same response time no matter how much load do you conduct and this response time is very low so everyone is happy. So

- if standard deviation is close to `0` - it is very good and means that response times distribution is minimal
- if standard deviation is close to arithmetic mean is not very good and means that there is a lot of dispersion in the measured values, like instead of getting 248 all the time you're getting between 124 496.

You can use chart like [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)) to see how does the trend look like, i.e. it might be the case response times are more or less stable during ramp-up phase and start to grow as more and more virtual users are onboarding.

Other option is that the server is behaving absolutely normally and the dispersion is due to [Connect Time/Latency](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) fluctuation